# Express server is not connecting to nodejs throwing error function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, ejs

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import user from '../components/Client';
import Editor from '../components/Editor';
import { initSocket } from '../socket';
import ACTIONS from '../action';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
const Compiler = () => {
    const socketRef = useRef(null);
    const location = useLocation();
    const reactNavigator = useNavigate();
    const { roomId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        const init = async () => {
            socketRef.current = await initSocket();
            socketRef.current.on('connect_error', (err) => handleErrors(err));
            socketRef.current.on('connect_failed', (err) => handleErrors(err));

            function handleErrors(e) {
                console.log('socket error', e);
                alert("Socket connection failed")
            }
            socketRef.current.emit(ACTIONS.JOIN, {
                roomId,
                username: location.state?.username,
            });
        };
        init();
    }, []);
    const [clients, setClients] = useState([
        { socketId: 1, username: 'aman' },
        { socketId: 2, username: 'am2an' },
    ])
    if (!location.state) {
        return < Navigate to="/" />;
    }
    return <div className='mainblock'>
        <div className='sidebar'>
            <div className='innersidebar'>
                <div className='logo'>
                    <img src='/logo1.png' alt='logo' className='logoimg' />
                </div>
                <h3>Connected</h3>
                <div className='clientsList'>
                    {
                        clients.map((client) => (
                            <client key={client.socketId} username={client.username} />
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <button className='btn copybtn'>Copy Room ID</button>
            <button className='btn leavebtn'>Leave</button>
        </div>
        <div className='editorblock'>
            <Editor />
        </div>
    </div>
};

export default Compiler;
```

This is the compiler landing page where the user lands and joins the server

here we accept the username and a roomid

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const ACTIONS = require('./src/action');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

const userSocketMap = {};
function getallConnectedClients(roomId) {
    return Array.from(io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomId) || []).map((socketId) => {
        return {
            socketId,
            username: userSocketMap[socketId],
        };
    })
}
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('socket connected', socket.id);
    socket.on(ACTIONS.JOIN, ({ roomId, username }) => {
        userSocketMap[socket.id] = username;
        socket.join(roomId);
        const clients = getallConnectedClients(roomId);
    })
})




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

this is the server code idk what is wrong

Here is the alert

can anyone help me with this[image]

I tried to reset the whole server and checked all the parameters which are used but nothing seems to work here

Here is the socket.js file

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
export const initSocket = () => {
    const options = {
        'force new connection': true,
        reconnection: true,
        reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
        timeout: 10000,
        transports: ['websocket'],
    };

    const socket = io(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL, options);

    socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
        console.log('Socket connection error:', error);
    });

    socket.on('connect_timeout', () => {
        console.log('Socket connection timeout');
    });

    socket.on('reconnect', (attemptNumber) => {
        console.log(`Socket reconnected after attempt ${attemptNumber}`);
    });

    return socket;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

In your backend, do this:

```
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        methods: ['GET','POST'],
    }
});
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: By setting up CORS like this, you're explicitly stating that your Socket.IO server should only accept connections from the specified origin (http://localhost:3000) and should only allow the specified HTTP methods (GET and POST). Any requests coming from other origins or using different methods will be rejected by the browser.

You can check the docs:
https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

Comment: Not working still getting the user-defined error

Comment: but still getting socket connection failed error?

Comment: yes nothing seems to work

Comment: Can you put your initSocket() function?

Comment: export const initSocket = async () => {
    const options = {
        'force new connection': true,
        reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
        timeout: 10000,
        transports: ['websocket'],
    };

Comment: It is incomplete. Can you update the question with initSocket function?

Comment: yeah i've updated the question with the socket.js file

Comment: Are you sure that process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL is http ://localhost:5000 ? Can you try to put it and you see if works?

const socket = io('__your backend url on 5000__', options);

Comment: yeah got it stored the address in an .env file solved the problem

Comment: yes solved......